# Store XML Data in a mongodb collection

Tags: xml, mongodb

I am still relatively new to NoSQL databases like mongodb, so excuse my ignorance.

**Background:**

Right now, I have a system that does the following:

1. gathers system data from clients
2. outputs that info into an xml document
3. a perl script takes the data in the xml tags and puts it in a mySQL db.
4. an apache/php powered website displays the data.

The purpose of this system is to act as an inventory for servers/chassis/network devices/etc.

This has been an okay system, but I have decided to go to a non-relational database because of the advantages I see in using that for the type of data I am storing.

**Question:**

1. Is it very simple to extract information from xml documents with mongodb?
2. Should I rewrite the scripts I have to output a JSON/BSON file instead of XML?
3. How do you take the information from files and put it into a mongodb database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When moving to a NoSQL document DB, the decision is highly influenced by **how the data is read or used by the client/user** as the data is mostly pre-aggregated/pre-joined based on the usage patterns. So, technically you can move to mongodb "technically" by just converting the data to json/bson instead of xml while importing the data.

Comment: So, you think it would be better to just change a few steps earlier in the processes? I kinda thought that too, but I just wanted to ask since it will be some doing.

Comment: @Jeff The point I am trying to make is that though it is as simple as changing few steps in the import process to move data to the mongodb, it is not that simple to answer how the data should be stored in mongodb to support your use-case without knowing how the data will be used.

Comment: @Jeff Based on your updated info I can only infer that this is mainly a inventory holder so you can safely move to mongodb thus gaining the schema-free advantage.

Answer (score 5):

1. MongoDB doesn't support xml document. All documents in mongodb are stored in [BSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/) format.
2. Yes, you can do that.
3. Mongodb [drivers](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/) are available for many languages. Use them.

Answer (score 2):

All documents in mongodb are stored in BSON format. You can store xml as a String value to the database. like -  `{xml : "<root><test>Test XML</test></root>"}`

Comment: Well this is faking :)

Answer (score -1):

In java you can do like this -

```
TestXML testXML = new TestXML();
        testXML.setXmlKey("test1" + new Date());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                "C:/xml/newxml.xml")));
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line.trim());
        }

        testXML.setXmlValue(sb.toString());
        mongoTemplate.save(testXML);
```

you can read that xml using below java code

```
List<TestXML> dbObjects = mongoTemplate.findAll(TestXML.class);
        for(TestXML key : dbObjects){
            System.out.println(key.getXmlValue());
        }
```