# Good Practice to store XML files - Express, MongoDB

Tags: xml, mongodb, express

I'm Working on an app with Express & MongoDB that stores XML files. Knowing that I don't need to query the file by its content, what's considered best practice in this scenario :

- Store the XML file as a string ;
- Convert the file to JSON and then store it.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610607/store-xml-data-in-a-mongodb-collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how big your files are, you could consider [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/). It's a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed the BSON-document size limit of 16 MB.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for (y) Thx :D

Comment: @bboulahdid The best way to say _thanks_ is upvoting and accepting my answer :)

Comment: Done ;) Thank you Again Sir!